# How to export dict list to csv cleanly?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a script I'm writing to make pulling data from my fantasy football league easy and exported in a format that can be played with in Excel easily.

The script I have attached only contains the relevant parts to this questions as the larger script I have written has a lot of moving parts that doesn't apply here.

I'm essentially pulling this `players.get_all_players()` data from the Sleeper platform using the Sleeper-API-Wrapper ([Github link here](https://github.com/NotTheCrocHunter/sleeper-api-wrapper)).

My script will take player data and put it into a .csv like this, with the player ID in the top row and all the info in a single cell below the ID. Screenshot of this below.

[Excel .csv screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBD4V.png)

How can I export this so that the data is nicely formatted into separate rows? I have a different spreadsheet where I'd like to be able to pull this data to automatically.

Alternatively, if I'm doing this in a really roundabout way, please let me know! This is the JSON response from the platform: [JSON Response](https://docs.sleeper.app/#fetch-all-players)

```
# 9 All players - players.get_all_players()

warning = 1
while warning == 1:
    print("%s%s\n\n\nWARNING:%s" % (fg(15), bg(9), attr(0)))
    print("%s%sthe 'all players' option is intensive and may freeze your PC for several minutes.%s" % (fg(15), bg(0), attr(1)))
    warning = input("continue anyway? (y/n)\n")
    if warning == "n":
        pe_loop = 0
        action = 0
    elif warning == "y":
        name = "all players"; file = name
        output = players.get_all_players()
        break
    else:
        print("Not a valid option, try again.")
        warning = 1

overwrite = 0
name_change = 0
while action == 0:
    try:
        action = int(input("%s%s\n1 - print\n2 - export to Excel\n3 - back to tasks\n4 - end\n--------------------\n%s" % (fg(14), bg(0), attr(1))))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid option, try again.")

## Print
    if action == 1 and week != 18:
        print(output)
        break

    elif action == 1 and week == 18:
        week = 0
        while week < 18:
            week += 1
            if task == 3:
                output = league.get_matchups(week)
            elif task == 4:
                output = league.get_transactions(week)
            print(output)

## Export
    elif action == 2:
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, file)
        name_change = input("\nDo you want to name the file? (y/n)\n")
        if name_change == "y":
            name = input("\nEnter file name now:\n")
        if name_change == "n":
            file_path = path + "\\" + name + '_' + str(year) + ".xlsx"
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) == True:
                overwrite = input("\nFile name... '" + name + "' already exists! Would you like to overwrite this file? (y/n)\n")
                if overwrite == "n":
                    count = 0
                    while os.path.isfile(file_path) == True:
                        count += 1
                        new_name = name + "_" + str(count)
                        file_path = path + "\\" + new_name + ".xlsx"

                    else:
                        name = new_name
                    
                    print("\nThe new file was automatically named: " + new_name + "_wk" + str(week) + "\nand placed in: " + path)
                    
        if os.path.isdir(path) == False and overwrite == 0:
            os.mkdir(path)
            print("\nCreating new file path... " + file + "\n")
        elif os.path.isdir(path) == True and overwrite == 0:
            print("\nFile path... '" + file + "' exists!\n")
        toCSV = output

# 9 All Players CSV file
        with open(parent_dir + file + "\\" + name + ".csv", 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as output_file:
            fc = csv.DictWriter(output_file, output.keys())
            fc.writeheader()
            fc.writerow(toCSV)
```

Comment: If you're looking for csv/spreadsheet/dataframe maninulation and beautification pandas is a great tool.  If you convert your output to a pandas dataframe you can save it as a csv with df.to_csv

Comment: It isn't clear why you've included all that code??  are you just trying to print a list of lists (or dictionaries) into a .csv file?  What have you tried?  You should be able to write a csv file very quickly and excel is happy to open .csv files.

Comment: If `toCSV` is a list of dictionaries, use `fc.writerows()`. `writerow()` if for writing a single row, not all the rows at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `sleeper_wrapper` exposes a [method `players.get_players_df`](https://github.com/NotTheCrocHunter/sleeper-api-wrapper/blob/91d8cf1b64cf55884b4c4746d53ccd1259d11c1f/sleeper_wrapper/players.py#L41) that gives you a pandas DataFrame containing all players.

Write that to a csv file using [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) as suggested in the comments.

Strip down your code to receive better answers faster :)
This is the code that your question needs:

```py
from sleeper_wrapper import Players
import csv

players = Players()
toCSV = players.get_all_players()

with open(parent_dir + file + "\\" + name + ".csv", 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as output_file:
            fc = csv.DictWriter(output_file, output.keys())
            fc.writeheader()
            fc.writerow(toCSV)
```

This is how you write the csv using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sleeper_wrapper import Players

players = Players()
all_players = players.get_all_players()
# stolen from https://github.com/NotTheCrocHunter/sleeper-api-wrapper/blob/91d8cf1b64cf55884b4c4746d53ccd1259d11c1f/sleeper_wrapper/players.py#L41
# because that method is unavailable in the version of sleeper_wrapper in PyPI
all_players_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_players, orient="index")
# all_players_df contains some information on teams as well, maybe you want to filter that out...
all_players_df.to_csv("your_output_file.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at this and try it out. I cut my code down, I was trying to keep it so it would still run correctly, but I see how all that extra stuff would make it harder to understand.

Comment: You're welcome. I think what I put into my question runs fine and contains the essence of your question. The user input queries are unnecessary for what you are asking. Strip them away and Keverley or AirSquid might have answered your question an hour ago.